# What is the number of subsets at size $k$ of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that if a subsets contains $2$ it does not contain $1$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> What is the number of subsets at size $k$ of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that if a subsets contains $2$ it does not contain $1$?

So  think about that. We have $n$ numbers and $k$ subgroups. If $2$ contains so have groups on size $(k-1)n +$, but how to start with that.

Consider the set $A=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ .Count the number of subsets of $A$ of cardinality $k$. How many subsets of cardinality on size $k$ do contain the number $2$ and not $1$?

Comment: In what sense do you mean 'subgroups' (probably not algebraically?) It would help if you defined more precisely what you are trying to count here.

Comment: Is this a group (a set together with a binary operation that is associative, has a neutral element, and inverses), or do you mean set and subsets (which some people sometimes translate as “group” and “subgroups”)?

Comment: yes i mean that  - set and subsets (which some people sometimes translate as “group” and “subgroups” . i need to count how much sub group i have on size k of the grop {1...n}

Comment: @thebesthere.  Mathematically the translation is a blunder.

Comment: maybe now its clear .. thanks :) Consider the set A={1....n} .Count the number of subsets of A of 
cardinality k. How many subsets of cardinality on size k do contain the number 2 and not 1

Answer (score 3):

**HINTS:**

You need the number of subsets of size $k$ that do not contain both $1$ and $2$.  This is the number of subsets of size $k$ minus the number of subsets of size $k$ that contain both $1$ and $2$.  If a subset of size $k$ contains both $1$ and $2$, then it must contain $k-2$ elements other than $1$ and $2$.

Can you finish it now?

**EDIT**

The answer is $${n\choose k}-{n-2\choose k-2}$$

Comment: SO the answer is   (
n−2
k−1
)

Comment: @thebesthere Do you mean ${n-2\choose k-1}$?

Comment: yes but why the answer is (
n
k
)−(
n−2
k−2
) if u can explain plz =]

Comment: The first paragraph explains it.  Which part do you have trouble understanding?  By the way, you can format ${n\choose k}$ as `${n\choose k}$`

Comment: It is not true that ${n \choose k} - {n-2 \choose k-2} = {n-2 \choose k-1}$.

Comment: OH ok t so the number of subset at size k that if subject contains 2 and not 1 is  ${n\choose k}$ - ${n-2\choose k-2}$??

Comment: Yes, that's correct.